# page-front.tpl.php not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am setting a template for the frontpage in a drupal 7 site and am having difficulty. I saved the file in the correct folder, cleared all caches, and refreshed both the theme page and browser page. Is there something I am missing? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: WHat does it mean "not work"?
Error in Drupal or just a blank page?

Comment: The added styles just weren't showing, so it was still showing the original page.tpl and not page-front.tpl which should have been page--front.tpl

Answer (score 26):

In Drupal 7, I believe you need [page--front.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/732168) -- note the two dashes.

Answer (score 3):

[theme_get_suggestions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7), which is called from [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) as `theme_get_suggestions(arg(), 'page')`, contains the following code:

```
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  // Front templates should be based on root only, not prefixed arguments.
  $suggestions[] = $base . $delimiter . 'front';
}
```

`$base` contains `"page"` and `$delimiters` contains `"__"`. As the underscores are replaced with hyphens, the template filename for the front page must be page--front.tpl.php (two hyphens instead of one).